# BBDD con el python shell, donde estan lo objetos que cree

Tags: python, base-de-datos, django, django-models

hola estoy aprendiendo a usar django y estoy empezando a jugar con la api de la base de datos, la duda que tengo es la siguiente

cuando instancio un objeto de una clase (tabla de la BBDD)
ejemplo:

```
>>>from app.models import Articulos
>>>art=Articulos(nombre='mesa', precio=1500)
>>>art.save()
```

bien hasta ahí todo bien, pero si cierro y vuelvo a abrir la api no puedo volver a llamar al objeto

ejemplo:

```
>>>art.nombre
```

me sale el error que 'art' no esta definido, y al escribir

```
>>>Articulos.objects.all()
```

ahí sigue el objeto que cree pero no puedo jugar con el, porque pasa esto ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que la shell es para hacer pruebas y mientras se usa todo(**historial, imports, funciones** y etc...) se guarda en memoria hasta el momento que sales, porque no tiene sentido guardar algo que es de prueba.

El siguiente caso

```
>>>art = Articulos(nombre='mesa', precio=1500)
>>>art.save()
```

Lo que haces es guardar el articulo en tu base de datos y guardas la referencia en una variable, pero si cierras la `shell` esa variable desaparece(pero el articulo en BBDD no) por lo cual ya no tienes acceso a esa variable la próxima vez que vuelvas a abrir la `shell`.

Después

```
>>>Articulos.objects.all()
```

Lo que estas diciendo aquí es que te traiga **TODOS** los artículos de tu base de datos por lo cual te devolverá una lista con los artículos, de manera que si quieres mostrarlos deberías iterar sobre ellos de siguiente modo

```
# Obtener todos los artículos 
articulos = Articulos.objects.all()
# Iterar sobre los mismos
for articulo in articulos:
    print(articulo.nombre)
```

Entonces sabiendo esto, la pregunta es **¿Que debería hacer si vuelvo a iniciar la `shell`  de nuevo?**

La respuesta es fácil, simplemente tienes que importar tu modelo y luego buscar la información que necesitas de ese modelo, por ejemplo si quiero recuperar un modelo en concreto

```
from app.models import Articulos
#Obtener un articulo por el titulo(mejor id siempre)
art = Articulos.objects.get(nombre='mesa')
print(art.nombre, art.precio)
```

Te recomiendo que eches un vistazo a la documentación de `django`  que esta muy muy bien explicado todo(y en español también).

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: ok muchas gracias